# Relationship Between Hessian and Gradient for Inequality about Convex Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

"Let $f:\mathcal{O} \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $f \in C^2(\mathcal{O})$, $\mathcal{O}$ an open convex set. Assume that $D^2f(x)$ is positive semi-definite $\forall x \in \mathcal{O}$. Prove that $f(x) \geq f(a) + \nabla f(a) \cdot (x-a)$, $\forall x \in \mathcal{O}$."

I feel like I could probably answer this question if I knew the relationship between $D^2f(a)$, the hessian matrix, and $\nabla f(a)$, the gradient. In other words, I feel like I should apply the positive semi-definiteness of $D^2f(a)$ somehow, but I don't know how to. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody seemed to care I had to figure it out myself. Here's the answer for anyone who might care in the future.

Consider the first degree Taylor approximation of $f$, $P_{1, a}(x) = f(a) + \nabla f(a)(x-a)$. The remainder, $R_{1, a, \theta}$ (for some $\theta \in [0, 1]$), is going to be positive or zero since $D^2f(x)$ is positive semi-definite. Thus we see that, since $f(x) = P_{1, a}(x) + R_{1, a, \theta}(x)$, we do have $f(x) \geq P_{1, a}(a) =  f(a) + \nabla f(a)(x-a)$.